# Insert multiple inputs into a select menu

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use one input field to populate a `<select><option>`. the caveat is that I want to add multiple inputs into the selects but I am struggling to add more than one. It is hard to explain but the flow is I am adding team names into inputs which then appear in a dropdown selects for a user/member.

Here is how I am currently doing this:

This adds multiple fields.

```
    <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">
          <input type="text" name="teamName" id="teamName">
          <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
    </div>
```

The input from the field then populates the following field:

```
    <label>Select Team</label>
        <select id="teamList">
    </select>
```

And this is handled like so:

```
  $('#teamName').on('change', function() {
    var $selectEl = $('#teamList');
    var $dashboardOption = $selectEl.find('.team-name');
    if ($dashboardOption.size()) {
        $dashboardOption.attr('value', $(this).val()).text($(this).val());
    } else {
        $selectEl.append('<option class="team-name" value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
    }
  });
```

My question here is, how do I insert multiple inputs into the select/option as stated above? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your change event is bound to one single input element, with the id "teamName". If you are going to have multiple input boxes which you want to perform this function, then you can use a class, so that the event is bound to all of them, something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="teamName" class="teamInputs">
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change', '.teamInputs', function() {
```

Note that I've used delegated event syntax, so that the change event will be triggered on all inputs with the class "teamInputs", even if they don't yet exist when this code is run.